# Ionic 3 - ion-slide inline css

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass, ionic3

I have Ionic3 App and ion-slides component on main page.

```
<ion-slides pager>
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let blog of blogs | async" >
      <h2>{{ blog.title }}</h2>
      <p>
      <a target="_blank" class="slider-read-more" ion-button outline color="secondary" (click)="blogDetail(blog)">ვრცლად</a>
      </p>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

I want to add inline css background image using style

```
<ion-slide *ngFor="let blog of blogs | async" style="background:url(blog.image) no-repeat center center fixed;">
```

but can't pass blog.image inside. how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try as shown below:

i.e. use `backgroundImage` as a property binding:

```
 <ion-slide [style.backgroundImage]="'url(' + blog.image + ')'"> ...
```

Comment: I've edited the answer, could you please try now @GochaGochitashvili ?

Comment: Great. We both must Thank to @sebaferreras Thanks `Sebaferreras` :)

Comment: Np, glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

I have used ngStyle directive to set an ion-slides style. v-3.0

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + blog.image + ')'}"
```